# Convert 01-Jun-2012 varchar to date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table where the dates (unfortunately) were brought in as varchar.  For example, I have a varchar date of 01-Jun-2012.  How do I convert this to yyyy-mm-dd format?  I have tried and failed with alter table, str_to_date and convert.  I am working in MySQL -Thank you! singh.rbir answered my issue, thank you! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTrSv.png)

Comment: Use [STR_TO_DATE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) with proper format pattern `'%d-%b-%Y'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it's SQL Server, the normal convert function should work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '01-Jun-2012');
```

will result in:

```
2012-06-01
```

Btw, it's not a good idea to show your production level database and other tables in that image. If this is a real world/commercial application, although security risk is very low due to limited info available, it's still not recommended to publicize table names or the like.

Comment: Ugh, I wish I knew the exact type of server this is on.  I am new to SQL, forgive my ignorance.  That did not work.

Comment: In that select query in the image, you're supplying `'productiondate'` as a string and not the actual column (without single quotes), do you think that has smth to do with this?

Comment: Actually, I believe the above query will not work until you change the column type from `varchar` to `date` as the convert function will return a date type.

Comment: Glad I was of help. Can you please accept my answer if the problem was solved? @au80403

Comment: singh.rbir - I will!  Am trying to figure that out! I think I did, please let me know if you do not see the credit you are due!

Comment: @au80403 Yea I don't think I see the points. I think you have to click on "upvote" and "accept answer" tick mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it's tagged to be mysql this will work

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01-Jun-2012','%d-%b-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

The second parameters are a format strings explained [here](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date)

Comment: Which is what str_to_date returns